# How to register a gitlab runner after starting the pod in Rancher

Tags: docker, kubernetes, gitlab, gitlab-ci, rancher

I'm trying to run a gitlab-runner in rancher with the image `gitlab/gitlab-runner:v14.0.1` but the pod does not register itself when i start the pod. Is there a way to do this without using helm, just using rancher?

I have tested the image [`sgillespie/gitlab-runner`](https://hub.docker.com/r/sgillespie/gitlab-runner) and it worked fine but i want to run the official image.

Comment: You could try setting the entrypoint and commands to the ones used by the image that was working for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying everything including copy the entrypoints commands to rancher i have decided to use the image [sgillespie/gitlab-runner](https://hub.docker.com/r/sgillespie/gitlab-runner) since it works fine.